# How do you return the updated object when updating in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get the objectId back when updating by another field in mongo. The code I have at the moment is:

```
twitterDb.update({'twitterId': t.id},tweetData, {upsert:true}, function(err, twitterDb) {
//do stuff here
});
```

note that twitterId is different from the objectId.

How do I return the full object so that I can get the objectId?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Mongoose's findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate). Provided you also know the *_objectId* of the Document you want to update, I think it should suit your needs.

Otherwise, you will need to find it first, modify it, and save it :

```
twitterDb.find({'twitterId': t.id}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    user.tweetData = tweetData;
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
       else
           //...
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think so, unless I'm misunderstanding the findByIdAndUpdate function. This only finds the id of the ObjectId created by mongo itself, not a specific field that I am defining.

So the object would look something like:

{
    _id: xxx,
    twitterId: xxx
}

and can only be updated by indexing the _id not twitterId, correct?

Comment: Haha :P just saw your update, fair enough, so there's no way of doing it in one step?

Comment: @DarylRodrigo : Yes, sorry, saw your comment when I finished my update :/

If you know the *real* `_id` of your Document, `findByIdAndUpdate` will work, and return the full object, with the updated fields.
If you don't, no, to my knowledge, there is no way to do that in one step.

Quoting from Mongoose docs, *"if we don't need the document returned in our application and merely want to update a property in the database directly, Model#update is right for us. If we do need the document returned in our application there is another, [findByIdAndUpdate is] often better option."*